# swatches option validation for ajax add to cart issue detail page

Tags: swatches, magento-2.1.9, ajaxaddtocart

I have installed Magento2.1.9  I have enabled ajax add to cart functionalities for product detail page. 
By following code

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {
                "bindSubmit": true //by default it was "false" for ajax cart i have changes to "true" 
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Ajax add to cart button is not validation the swatches option of configurable product on click it's going to submit without any validation of swatches option.

But when i have disabled ajax add to cart it's working fine.

Please help on above issue.Any references and suggestion is highly appreciated.